# characters being skipped being output file i/o

Tags: c, io

I have a function meant to encrypt a file by replacing each character with the character three letters before, but I'm having some issues with the output.

```
void file_encrypt(char * filename)
{
    FILE *file1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    char c;

    if(file1 != NULL) {
        while(fscanf(file1, "%c", &c) == 1) {
            c = fgetc(file1);
            if(c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == ' ') {
                switch(c) {
                    case 'a': putchar('x');
                        break;
                    case 'b': putchar('y');
                        break;
                    case 'c': putchar('z');
                        break;
                    case ' ': putchar(' ');
                        break;
                }
            }
            else 
                printf("%c", c - 3);
        }
    }  
}
```

my input file is a text file containing `aaaaa bbbbb ccccc def` as a simple test, so my output *should* be `xxxxx yyyyy zzzzz abc` but instead it's `xx yy zz b`.

I've tried messing around with the while loop condition (making it `!= EOF` instead of `== 1`, changing the `fscanf` to a `fgetc` check) the `c = fgetc(file1)` statement had previously been `fscanf(file1, "%c", &c)` to assign the char to the address of c, same result.

Looking at it now I can see that it is reading or writing every other character rather, including skipping the first one. Anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: Please read the manual for `fgetc` carefully, especially paying attention to its return type and value.

Comment: `while(fscanf(file1, "%c", &c) == 1) {
            c = fgetc(file1);` reads from `file1` twice.  Is that your intention?

Comment: ahhh I see, reading from the file twice was my issue. I didn't realize that the check from the while loop was actually reading from the file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the loop, you read twice from the file, ignoring the first value read (into `c`, by `fscanf()`):

```
    while(fscanf(file1, "%c", &c) == 1) {
        c = fgetc(file1);
```

You probably want to simplify this to read only once:

```
    int c;   // EOF is not a 'char' value
    while ((c = fgetc(file1)) != EOF) {
```